# How to make service up and running even though admin account log off

Tags: windows-server-2003-r2

Hi we are using Windows server 2003. Windows services using admin credentials while restarting. Whenever admin account was logged off services were going down. Because of this we are maintaining admin account in disconnected or active status.

We installed Glassfish server as a service in windows.It uses admin credentials while restarting the service from 'services.msc'. When we log off admin account Glassfish server was going down. Can we do anything to make server running even admin account log off.

Also tell me whether we should use admin account in disconnected mode or we have any solution for this problem.

Comment: What kind of services? how do execute them?

Comment: `1.` That doesn't make sense. Services don't stop running because the user account they're running under is logged off. `2.` Create a dedicated service account for this purpose. `3.` We need more detail. `4.` Can you provide a screenshot of the `Log On` tab of the service in question?

Comment: We installed Glassfish server as a service in windows.It uses admin credentials while restarting the service from 'services.msc'. When we log off admin account Glassfish server was going down. Can we do anything to make server running even admin account log off.

Comment: If you've properly configured it as a service yet it only works when admin is logged in and/or quits when admin logs out, then either it doesn't support being run as a service and doesn't appreciate your attempts to make it do so, or it's generally a piece of unstable rubbish. In either case, you probably need to take this up with them.

Comment: Windows 2003 is gonna be end of extended support in a year. Plan ahead and replace it.

Answer (score 1):

Forgive me if I have got the wrong idea about this ticket but I think you are getting caught out by the Security Policy.

If you launch `Secpol.msc` from command prompt on that Server and drill down to Local Policies and User Rights Assignment. There is a section in here for Log on as a service, if this only has Network Service then you will have issues and need to add any account name that will be used to start services under.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your actual issue about the Glassfish "service".

If it is a service that requires an interactive desktop (which sounds plausible based on the issues), then get FireDaemon (google it, it's cheap but not free) and setup the service using FireDaemon to use an interactive desktop.  Then you can logoff the server no problem and the service will continue to run in Session 0.